# Taptic engine (trackpad) stays on after shut down from Windows 10

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, trackpad, dual-boot

I have an Early 2015 Macbook Pro 13-inch Model that has 6 operating systems manually installed on it (High Sierra, Yosemite, Android x86, Windows, Ubuntu and Kali Linux). As I said, I installed Windows manually, without using the BootCamp assistant.

About 2 weeks ago, I upgraded Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. After that, I reinstalled BootCamp helper, since it was broken after the upgrade. It reinstalled successfully. It was all normal from that point.

**However,** yesterday I noticed that the Taptic Engine (trackpad) stayed on every time I shut down my computer when it was booted up from Windows 10 (this doesn’t happen when shut down from other OSes). Is this normal behaviour? If not, how can I fix it?

**EDIT 1:** I have just discovered something strange. If I shutdown Windows using Classic Shell’s shutdown button, the problem happens. But when I shut down using `shutdown -s -t 0`, it shuts down the computer and turns off the taptic engine too. I will disable Classic Shell and try to shutdown and tell the results.

Comment: Have you tried removing Windows 10 and seeing if the behaviour continues? What about a fresh install of windows 10 without upgrading from 8?

Comment: I have found a workaround/fix for the problem. I will post an answer when possible.

Comment: Since I just started this account I can't post comments. I have the same issue and it's actually quite annoying, I've linked it to an issue where the touch bar stops working *if* the trackpad is clickable when turning it off in windows. > I have found a workaround/fix for the problem. I will post an answer when possible. – pixelomer Please share it! I need it!